# Why Klocwork complains that S_IRWXU is an int?

Tags: linux, lint, mkfifo, klocwork

Here is the code:

```
char path = "/temp/abc";
if (mkfifo(path, S_IRWXU) != -1)
{
    /* Other codes. */
}
```

For the if check, I got Klocwork misra:
**Operand of bitwise operation has type 'int' instead of 'unsigned integer'**

And at the same line, lint says:
**Violates MISRA 2004 Required Rule 10.1, Prohibited Implicit Conversion: Signed versus Unsigned**

But I understand the second argument taken by mkfifo is of type **mode_t**, which should actually be an unsigned integer. Thus as we know

```
#deinf S_IRWXU  (__S_IREAD|__S_IWRITE|__S_IEXEC)
```

there should be no problem.

Any idea why I got such warnings?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Klocwork is, but my guess is that S_IRWXU and the other constants are defined either as enums, or as C preprocessor #defines to integer literals; in both case they would thus have the type [signed] int; hence the mismatch.